# Install Cakephp in a sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am a newbie to cakephp.I had a previous cakephp project in root folder (Ex: www.example.com), now I have moved the files to a sub-folder 'folder1' (Ex: www.example.com/folder1). The site is working, but the images and the other sub paths are pointing to the old root link.

The **folder1** .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST>
#require valid-user
</Limit>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /folder1/
        RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
        RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The **folder1/app**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /folder1/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

The **folder1/app/webroot**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /folder1/

    # Add trailing slash to urls
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,5})$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ $1$2/ [R=301,L]

    # Skip files and pass requests to cake
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Please can anyone help me solve this issue.

Comment: Show your source of images and the other sub paths.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, goto app/config/core.php and make changes to this line,

`Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http://localhost/folder1');`

Comment: Yes Thank You, Tried with this, But dint helped out.